# ADF Faces escape button doesn't trigger SelectionEvent for a SelectionListener af:table

Tags: java, jsf, listener, oracle-adf, selectionchanged

Why doesn't escape button notifies me that the selection changed ? (to unselected)
I have some validation on SelectionListener and pressing escape is jumping over my validation. 
This is definitely not a normal behavior. I could do some JS when pressing escape from the table to press a hidden button to catch that event. 
Am I missing something ?
A weird behavior is that for some other table the selectionEvent does get triggered at Escape Key !! ?

Comment: Which component's selection are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad. it works, my business seemed that the listener wasn't called.